# Wasser siedet oder Wasser kocht?

Tags: difference, word-choice

In which cases do you use *Wasser siedet* and when *Wasser kocht*? It looks like the two aren’t synonyms.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Sieden* is a scientific term, describing one of the two variants of the change of a liquid to a gas. The variant *sieden* describes the variant, where the [vapor pressure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vapor_pressure) is at least the surrounding pressure. In that case, gas bubbles develop inside the liquid, which then go up the liquid. (The other variant is *verdunsten* which happens if the vapor pressure is below the surrounding pressure.)

This term is rarely used outside of science or scientific applications.

*Kochen* is not a scientific term, but a cuisine term. In the case of water it describes very hot water. In traditional, european cuisine, this means *sieden*. But there are modern cuisines or cooking techniques which employ hot water below boiling temperature.

Comment: @Stephie OK, it's called `simmern` and `pochieren`. Changed the answer.

Comment: @Jan Ok, changed it.

Answer (score 7):

When I was young my grandmother told me that water *siedet* at around 90° – when you see the first bubbles (even though, scientifically that’s not correct. Maybe in cooking it’s working somehow). But I can't remember I ever used that term except in chemistry.

Once I was told there are some ideas to tie the chemists’ words closer to the spoken language. But I guess there are more people who use *sieden* instead of *kochen* than *Kochpunkt* instead of *Siedepunkt*. (Or *Frierpunkt*)

Comment: you talk about "sieden" as soon as you see the bubbles. you are right. "Sieden" starts before "kochen" , kochen is from 100°C+ and "sieden" is before 100°C .

Comment: Chemically you can't really boil water with more than 100°C. Basically in Austria you can't even reach 100°C (I live in a town about 600m above sea level). Here it starts to boil at around 96°C.
I think some teas refer to use `siedendes` water so it does not destroy the fabric of the bag.

Comment: Is that "Frierpunkt" you are talking about standard "Österreichisch". From Germany I only know "Gefrierpunkt"

Comment: Nobody says "Frierpunkt" this was more an ironic referrer to words which exist per definition but are hardly used

Comment: Frierpunkt sounds as if the water is just about to catch a cold.

Answer (score 4):

In modern everyday language one says *Wasser kocht bei 100 Grad*. *Sieden* has come out of use in normal language, its use in scientific areas has already been mentioned above. But members of the word family are still around. We speak of *Siedepunkt und Gefrierpunkt des Wassers* and of *Tauchsieder* or we say *Er ist ein hartgesottener Bursche*. Historically we can find Salzsiederei or Seifensieder or in older texts gesottenes Fleisch, Gebratenes und Gesottenes.

By the way the stem forms can be:

> *sieden, siedete, hat gesiedet* or
>   *sieden, sott, gesotten*

[sieden in DWDS](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=sieden)
In DWDS I’m missing the hint that *sieden* has come out of use in modern everyday language.

Answer (score 1):

Der *Siedepunkt* ist jene Temperatur, an dem Wasser vom flüssigen in den gasförmigen Zustand übergeht. Das passiert zunächst in der Nähe der Wärmequelle, also am Boden des Topfes: Wasser wird gasförmig und steigt (durch das noch flüssige Wasser) auf, es siedet. Von *kochen* spricht man erst dann, wenn das gesamte Wasser diese Temperatur erreicht hat, und wallt.

Der Unterschied ist im Alltag belanglos. Chemiker sprechen immer von *sieden* (nie kochen), in einem Kochrezept ist *siedendes* Wasser sehr heiß, aber gerad noch nicht vollkochend.

Comment: I as a chemist usually say *unter Rückfluss erhitzen* rather than *sieden* or *kochen*. If anything, I use the *Siedepunkt* in the lab.

Answer (score 1):

I rarely use *das Wasser siedet.* I know what it means but colloquially in my area (Thuringia) we say *das Wasser kocht.* You can say *das Wasser zum sieden bringen.* But again where I’m from that is rare. See the other answers for the definition of sieden.

Based on these you can use sieden as a reference point during cooking. It is earlier than full on boiling. Sieden would be the equivalent of boil in english according to Google translate. Though I myself would rather say it compares to simmer. Which is cooking but not at full heat.

Examples:

> Appliance: Wasserkocher
>
> Temperature: Siedepunkt
>
> Action: Wasser zum kochen bringen.
>
> State: Das Wasser hat die Siedetemperatur/Siedpunkt erreicht.
>
> State: Das Wasser kocht.
>
> State: Die Milch kocht über.
>
> State: Die Suppe muss auf mittlerer Hitze köcheln. (close to the Siedepunkt but not full power)

Answer (score -3):

The difference between the two is that nobody uses *das Wasser siedet* and you can use it only if the water is above 100 degrees Celsius.

Comment: Sorry for my bad english, I'm from germany ;)

Comment: yes and it's not correct ;)

Comment: Ok could be possible. Thanks for saying that :)

Comment: "sieden" is commonly used as a scientific term in Chemistry, so to say "nobody uses" it would be wrong. I also think @Toscho is right with the distinction between "sieden" and "kochen" being a scientific and a cuisine term, rather than a difference in temperature.